# Fastest MySQL way of matching and returning true and false

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of search words.

```
$unprocessed=array("language1 word1", "language1 word2", "language1 word3");
```

Each word in $unprocessed has an unique entry in a column called "language1"

If found, return row column "language2" else return false. It is important that if the word is not found, false is returned.

```
1. $unprocessed=array("language1 word1", "language1 word2", "language1 word3");

2. MySQL Query (what is best way?)

3. $processed=array(false,"language2 word2","language2 word3");
```

Is it possible to do this without looping a query?
What is best way: using WHERE="word", IN("word"), LIKE="word" or something else?

Comment: A query generally cannot return different data types in the same result field.

Comment: Does MySQL even have a `BOOLEAN` data type? `TINYINT(1)` is the closest thing isn't it?

Comment: Or `ENUM('No','Yes')` (or something similar)

Comment: i've read it 3 times and i still cant understand what is it... u have separate table for each language?

Comment: I have two columns, language1 and language2 in a given table. I want to search $unprocessed words and return $processed words. If an unprocessed word is found in language1 column, return language2, else return false.

Comment: Do an `IN` query, then do the rest (for the missing entries) on the client side.

Comment: ^ thats what I was thinking. But then I have to again search the results of the query for the corresponding words so that $unprocessed and $processed keys are aligned. I am trying to do something "If IN, show result, else return FALSE"

Comment: @MaciekSemik: So what. You need a loop to fix that on the client side. Big deal.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath when you have a few thousand entries across multiple tables, doing a loop for each word wouldn't be slow? That's why I am trying to find a MySQL solution

Comment: @MaciekSemik: It's quite hard to scale databases. It's trivial for the web-servers. Tend to push work to the web-servers.

Answer (score 1):

> Each word in $unprocessed has an unique entry in a column called "language1"

This means that you do **not** want to use LIKE. You could run a single query like this and return a single tuple with as many columns as requested words:

```
SELECT MAX(IF(language1=':word1', 1, 0)) AS hasWord1,
       MAX(IF(language1=':word2', 1, 0)) AS hasWord2,
       MAX(IF(language1=':word3', 1, 0)) AS hasWord3
FROM table WHERE language1 IN (':word1',':word2',':word3');
```

This is slightly more performant that three one-word query, especially if you have an index on `language1`. If you need more columns from the language table (i.e. not only the word but, say, its weight or its SVO status or...), you'd better ask for a tuple for each word. In this case, though, missing words *will not be returned* (anyway, you would have no data for them). A judicious use of LEFT JOIN plus the first query can be used to avoid this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE language1 IN (':word1',':word2',':word3');
```

or
    SELECT table2.* FROM table LEFT JOIN table AS table2 USING(primaryKey)
        WHERE table.language1 IN (':word1',':word2',':word3');

You can also get one column only to identify the word by using binary representation:

```
SELECT   MAX(IF(language1=':word1', 1, 0))
       + MAX(IF(language1=':word2', 2, 0))
       + MAX(IF(language1=':word3', 4, 0))
       AS wordMask, ...
```

or, in the case of a JOIN, it's enough to get an index:

```
SELECT   MAX(IF(language1=':word1', 1, 0)
       + MAX(IF(language1=':word2', 2, 0)
       + MAX(IF(language1=':word3', 3, 0)
       AS wordIndex, ...
```

To build the query, you can use a PHP `foreach` loop.

In case of a simple translate table:

```
SELECT MAX(IF(language1=':word1', language2, ':word1')) AS word1,
       MAX(IF(language1=':word2', language2, ':word2')) AS word2,
       MAX(IF(language1=':word3', language2, ':word3')) AS word3,
FROM table WHERE language1 IN (':word1',':word2',':word3');
```

will return word*n* containing either the original word, or the "translated" word from the language2 column:

```
 select MAX(IF(language1='computer', language2, '-')) AS hasWord1, MAX(IF(language1='ouijamaflip', language2, '-')) AS hasWord2 FROM tbl WHERE language1 IN ('computer', 'ouijmaflip');
+------------+----------+
| hasWord1   | hasWord2 |
+------------+----------+
| ordinateur | -        |
+------------+----------+
```

You can also have language priority, again building this in PHP:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(IF (language1=':word1',
        COALESCE(language2, language3, language4, ':default1')))
        AS word1,
```

You can set `$default` equal to `$word`, or maybe `"?{$word}?"` or similar.

```
$words = array( 'computer', 'bytes', 'processor' /*, 'other'... */);
$langs = array( 'language2', 'language3' /*, 'language4', ... */ );

$rets  = array();
$whrs  = array();
$defs  = array();
foreach ($words as $ndx => $word) {
    $rets[] = "COALESCE(IF (language1 = ':word{$ndx}', COALESCE("
            . implode(", ", $langs) . "), ':default{$ndx}')) AS word{$ndx}";
    $whrs[] = "':word{$ndx}'";
    $defs[] = "MISSING_{$word}";

}
$SQL = "SELECT " 
   . implode(", ", $rets) // All IFs
   . " FROM table WHERE language1 IN("
   . implode(", ", $whrs) . ");"; // All WHEREs
```

This will return a query such as:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(
        IF (language1='computer',
            COALESCE(language2, language3),
            'MISSING_computer')
    ) AS word1,
    COALESCE(
        IF(language1='bytes', 
            COALESCE(language2, language3),
            'MISSING_bytes')
    ) AS word2,
    COALESCE(
        IF(language1='processor',
           COALESCE(language2, language3),
           'MISSING_processor')
    ) AS word3
 FROM tbl
 WHERE language1 IN ('computer', 'bytes', 'processor');
```

and finally, with this tbl:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| language1 | language2  | language3 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| computer  | ordinateur | NULL      |
| bytes     | NULL       | ottetti   |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

it will return

```
+------------+---------+-------------------+
| word1      | word2   | word3             |
+------------+---------+-------------------+
| ordinateur | ottetti | MISSING_processor |
+------------+---------+-------------------+
```

*ordinateur* will be taken from the first language because it's there, *ottetti* comes from the second language since the first is NULL, and *processor* returns an error because it's completely missing or has all relevant columns NULL. You can distinguish these cases by adding "language1" (or a string such as 'EMPTY ROW') as the least priority language.

Comment: this is perfect, and if you need a real bool use php's `boolval()`

Comment: Very interesting. So this gives me ARRAY INDEX corresponding to the row in the table. So I now have to join to get the language2 value?

Comment: That's an easier case (added to answer). You can modify it to return, say, an empty string, or word1 concatenated with "*" to recognize an untranslated word. This is between 100% and 300% the speed of three queries, depending on data table size, indexing, clustering and IOSS caching. The faster the disk, the smaller the table, the better indexed, the most the speed will be the same (i.e. no difference between three queries and one returning three values). On MySQL over a slow network, conversely, you might appproach the 300% limit.

Comment: Is this much faster than doing a loop with a WHERE statement?

Comment: Depends on your setup, see previous comment. It usually is faster :  how much, you have to do some tests.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this and add 'IFNULL' to if statment success: if(language2='word1',ifnull(language3,language1),0)

Comment: I have modified the queries to return a single tuple (faster), and also added a sample code to build what *I think* is your use case. Feel free to add/modify if I thought wrong ☺

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, and according to the comments you can't do this with just MySQL, you'll need PHP to process it.

Assuming you're using pdo.. this pseudo code should do it for you

```
function whatever($unprocessed){
    global $db;
    $processed = array();
    foreach($unprocessed as $u){
        $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM language1 WHERE word = :wrd");
        $q->execute(array(":wrd"=>$u));
        $processed[] = $q->rowCount() ? $q->fetchColumn() : false;
    }
    return $processed;
}
```